# Dealing with skewed data but cannot use log-transformation

Tags: data-transformation, ordinal-data, skewness, data-preprocessing

It seems that the popular solution to dealing with skewed data is to apply log-transformation.

But in my case, the data is a rating score (range form 0-5). The distribution of the data looks like exponential distribution where there is really high number of 0 but very few 5.

[image: data distribution]

I tried log-transformation but it doesn't work at all. As I understand, log-transformation works only when the data have a wider range (like 0-1000) which it will follow Benford's law.

How could I transform it into normal distribution? or any suggestion to reduce this skewness?

---

More info:

1. My aim is not to focus on this particular task but ask for the more general idea where log-transformation cannot apply to resolve skewness.
2. the example above is discrete on range 0-5 with increments the value by 0.5 on each step.

Comment: Why do you want to transform your data? What are you doing with your data? Also, it looks like your ratings are not discrete between 0 and 5, so what are they actually?

Comment: What do you really want to do with your data? Regression? If so, look into *ordinal regression*, search this site.

Comment: Data is discrete with width = 0.5. I would like to do regression but actually, I would like to get an idea to work with this kind of data as it cannot apply log-transformation in this case.

Comment: You don't need transformations. Look at **ordinal regression** https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410421/analysis-for-ordinal-categorical-outcome and search this site!

Comment: It seems that you answered the wrong question