# MANCOVA Model in R

Tags: r, ordinal-data, mancova

I want to investigate the impact of marital status on the perceived sense of meaningfulness in people's live and control for gender and age.

So I have 6 different groups for marital status and an ordinal scale to assess meaningfulness. Marital status should be the predictor variable, age and gender the covariates.

What would be the correct way to formulate this model in R?

Comment: You need to give us some more context, such as sample size, details on the ordinal scale.  You could look into ordinal regression models, for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410421/analysis-for-ordinal-categorical-outcome.  Also : ...

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) 
here, but you may have a real statistical question buried 
here. You may want to edit your question to clarify the 
underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you 
understand the statistical concepts involved, the 
software-specific elements are self-evident or at least 
easy to get from the documentation.