# What statistical test should I use when comparing answers from a questionnaire between baseline and follow-up?

Tags: categorical-data, survey, ordinal-data

This is my first question, so I am sorry if there is some missing information.

I am unsure what statistical test I should use when I want to see if there is a difference from baseline to follow-up (dependent data) in how women answer the following question: “Does urine leak before you can get to the toilet?”. There are the following options:

```
Never About once a week or less often
Two or three times a week
Once daily
Several times a day

All the time
```

May data look like this for the drug A (placebo) group.

Groups: Treatment_group, Redcap_event_name [2]

Treatment_group Redcap_event_name OAB_UI n

```
1 Drug A Baseline Never 3
2 Drug A Baseline About once a week or less often 3
3 Drug A Baseline Two or three times a week 6
4 Drug A Baseline Once daily 3
5 Drug A Baseline Several times a day 2
6 Drug A Follow-up Never 5
7 Drug A Follow-up About once a week or less often 7
8 Drug A Follow-up Two or three times a week 3
9 Drug A Follow-up Once daily 1
10 Drug A Follow-up Several times a day 1
```

The data is categorical. But I don't know if the distance between the answers is the same or not - and what test to use to compare it between baseline and follow-up

Comment: I suggest you read the following references. Both are relatively short and easy to read: 1: https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/analyze-likert-scale-data/. 2: https://statisticsbyjim.com/hypothesis-testing/analyze-likert-scale-data/

Comment: Maybe look into ordinal regression, see  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410421/analysis-for-ordinal-categorical-outcome   What is your sample size?